# How to increase text size/icon size on Kali Linux

Tags: linux, desktop, gnome, xfce, kali-linux

[image: Desktop]

I have been trying to increase the overall resolution (not screen resolution) so that I can see what I am doing. I changed to 4 other desktop managers and I still cannot increase the size of the icons and text. I have also read some blogs about kali's broken display issue. However, there has to be some alternates!

Comment: In case you haven't tried, Xfce has an option to optimize font size under Appearance > Fonts > Custom DPI setting. Typical value is 96. Increase this value when displaying on larger screen.

Answer (score 0):

To change the Icon/Font size follow below steps :-

1. Navigate to **Appearance** using search bar.
2. You can change Style, Icons, Fonts.

See below for reference

[image: Appearance Menu in Kali]